# Collapsing table rows

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I apologize if this has already been asked elsewhere, I've seen some other questions here that are similar to this question, but I haven't found this specific issue.

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap 3 and I've got a table of data that users should be able to click the row and below the row another row will appear with a form to allow them to add/enter details about the row above.

I've succeeded in getting the rows to collapse and expand when clicked. When the row toggles, the row shows correctly, but once the expansion or collapse is complete, the row compresses to the first column despite colspan being set.

Here are the images of what I am talking about:

Prior to expansion starting:
[image: Prior to expansion starting]

During expansion:
[image: During expansion]

After expansion is complete:
[image: After expansion is complete]

Why would this be occurring? I'm using ASP.net, but other than assigning the id of the collapsable container and nesting it all in a data repeater, no asp controls are used for this. I don't think ASP would be the culprit, but I'm not sure.

Is this just not possible?

Here is the code for the tr that expands in the example above:

```
<tr>
    <td class="collapse" id="<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ID") %>" colspan="6">
        <div class="well col-sm-12">
            <div class="form-horizontal" role="form">
                <!-- FORM CONTENTS GO HERE --!>
            </div>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It appears that when the "in" class is applied to the td after collapsing is complete is the culprit. By debugging with Chrome, if I remove the classes "collapse in" and replace it with "collapsing" it shows fine. Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I just moved the functionality of the collapse to the tr tag rather than the td tag like so:

```
<tr class="collapse" id="<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ID") %>">
    <td colspan="6">
```

Works great now!